# При редактировании строки изменить ее положение?

Tags: php, алгоритм

Всем привет, есть текстовый файлик с строками такого вида:

```
1|Владимир|2000||1|
2|Олег|2000||1|
3|Виталий|2000||1|
4|Евгений|2000||1|
5|Станислав|2000||1|
```

Строки читаются с верху в низ.
Вывод через цикл for.

Как при редактировании зная позицию строки можно переместить ее строго после первых двух?
Тобишь есть строка **Станислав** ее ид 5 и позиция 4 (в массиве же от 0) и как эту позицию перенести на 3-ю?

Comment: А зачем? Какую проблему это решает?

Comment: Таких строк может быть 100-500. И значения их разные будут я про второй элемент массива (2000)  И при надобности  поднять к примеру 50-ю строку к верху но только после первых двух и если еще одну поднимать то после той что уже была поднята. Думаю можно добавить еще значение в массив и ставить туда надпись up чтобы понимать что она уже была поднята.

Comment: Зачем его поднимать? Чем плохо то что он сидит в своей позиции и всё?

Comment: Есть надобность такая. У вас есть возможность помочь в реализации такого?

Comment: Читаешь строки... Если это "не твоя строка" - тебе нужно знать дошел ты до нужно позиции при выводе или нет. Если еще не дошел - пиши строку смело. Если нужная позиция уже "ожидает" нужную строку - нужно записывать строки в некий "буфер"... Как только прочитана нужная строка - она записывается и после этого записываются все строки из "буфера". Далее строки читаются и записываются в обычном режиме "прочитал и записал"...

Answer (score 1):

Например вот так:

```
$element = $a[5];
unset($a[5]);
$result = array_merge(array_slice($a, 0, 2), [$element], array_slice($a, 2));
```

Здесь $a - это ваш исходный массив, по которому вы, как я понял, проходитесь циклом.
Функция array_slice() делит массив на части: в первой оказываются три начальных элемента, во второй - все остальные.
Функция array_merge() потом соединяет их обратно, вставляя между ними то, что вы захотите.

Comment: Здравствуйте, гуд только вот как теперь позицию менять не подскажите?

Comment: Так последняя строчка и меняет позицию выбранного элемента. В данном случае переменная $element будет поставлена на третье место, если считать с нуля.

Comment: Дак это все вывод на фронт. А мне нужно типо пост запросом изменить позицию строки в самом текстовом файле.

Comment: Мне непонятен комментарий. По шагам: что есть, а что должно получиться в итоге?